# Add hyperlinked image to email signature using vbscript, using str string

Tags: vbscript

I realize this has been answered numerous times in the past, but I'm just having an issue with the final step of my hyperlinked icon in an email signature

I am adding my image and hyperlinking using the code below which works great, but I need to substitute the actual URL with an attribute from AD. I currently use `strLinkedin =  objUser.homePhone` (I use `home.Phone` which is where I put the user's personal linkedin URL) and this works fine when I want to use `strLinked`, but I cannot seem to use it in the code below as the URL.

CODE - for images with a fixed URL (this works fine):

```
set objShape = objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("\\path\share\4.png")
objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add objShape, "https://twitter.com/example";
```

Need to have it similar to (this doesn't work obviously, it just makes the link the show `strLinkedIn`):

```
set objShape = objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(" \\path\share\4.png")
objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add objShape, "strLinkedIn"
```

Using the code just above, the output shows the text `strLinkedin` rather than the result of `strLinkedin =  objUser.homePhone`.

If someone could please possibly help me with the final 'tweak' that would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, code is:

strLinkedin =  objUser.homePhone

set objShape = objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("\path\share\4.png")

objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add objShape, strLinkedIn

Simply, no "".